# Excel macro, dd.mm date +1

Tags: vba, excel, date, macros

First time here, sorry if I'm doing something wrong

I just found out about excel macros and I think they will help me a lot, but I'm not really into programming and all this stuff

I did a few macros and it was really easy, but this one is not, at least not for me, I hope you can help me

I already tried a lot of stuff like NumberFormat and Format(...) but it didn't work how I wanted it to work

What I want is:

I get excel documents with a certain date in cell [F6] (formated dd.mm) like this: "01.08" , it's always 01 (first day of the month)

now I want a macro, that will take that date, and everytime I use the macro I want it to paste the next day in the cell I have currently selected (ActiveCell)

so when I use my macro for the first time in that document, I want it to paste "02.08" into the current cell I have selected

the next time I use it "03.08" etc..

I hope you understand me and can help me

Comment: Use `DateAdd`: `DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(Range("F6").Value))` 'The "d" stands for day, 1 is one day and DateValue(Range("F6").Value) gets the date you want to add a day to (You have to change the "F6" of course)

Comment: http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/write-data-to-worksheet-cell/  and you can just add days to dates, or you can use DATEADD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Note that `i` will be reset to 0 when you close the workbook. If you want to store `i` between sessions you have to write it to a cell and then reference that cell.
Cell F6 has to be properly formatted as Date.

```
Dim i As Long

Sub next_day()
    i = i + 1
    Selection = Range("F6").Value + i
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm"
End Sub
```